# Why does bash only sometimes read #-commented commands from history

Tags: bash, command-history

On my Arch Linux machine (5.2.15), history navigation with the arrow keys sees commands in `~/.bash_history` that start with the `#` character.

On my Mac OS machine (bash 3.2.57), history navigation with the arrow keys does not see commands in `~/.bash_history` that start with the `#` character.

The `history` builtin has the same behaviour: it sees those commands on the Arch machine, but not on OS X.  Running `history -r` doesn't cause the commented commands to show up, though I can see them in `~/.bash_history`.

What causes this difference in behaviour and how can I configure bash on Mac OS to behave like it does on Arch Linux (so I see commented history entries)?

Both machines have very similar bash configuration:

Mac OS:

```
$ shopt -p | grep hist
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s histappend
shopt -u histreedit
shopt -u histverify
shopt -u lithist
$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignorespace
```

Arch:

```
$ shopt | grep hist
cmdhist         on
histappend      on
histreedit      off
histverify      off
lithist         off
$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignorespace
```

Comment: Long dead version of Bash is buggy, news at 11. Jokes aside, FWIW, I can repro on a `centos:5` docker container, which has `3.2.25(1)`, but not on a `centos:6` container, which has `4.1.2(2)`. I'm betting this was a bug fixed with 4.0 or 4.1.

Comment: What are the values of `$HISTIGNORE` on the two machines? Does one of them include `#*`?

Comment: @terdon: unset on both -- but HISTIGNORE is about *saving* in history, which both machines do.  The problem is that the mac doesn't *load* commented commands from history.

Comment: I think @muru already answered the question, maybe add that as the answer muru?

Comment: OK. I just tried with `HISTIGNORE="#*"` and then ran `#foo` and pressing the UP button didn't bring it back. And it seems reasonable that it can't load something if it hasn't saved it. In any case, if it is indeed a bug in an old bash version, there's not much more to add.

Comment: if it is a bug that was fixed, I don't see anything relevant in the [`CHANGES` file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;a=blob;f=CHANGES;h=e4e0124f28021078caafe7a183cd6de13b19c71f;hb=HEAD), I'll look into it a bit more later and post an answer if I can find anything.

Comment: @terdon it saves it